# Home (re)Finance and Providing Additional Information

Tags: united-states, mortgage, refinance

Since mortgage refinance rules require substantial information, and the goal is to evaluate whether the borrower has the discipline and ability to repay the loan, it would make sense to gather evidence of the borrower's budgeting plans, and their employment expectations.

Although I am not an expert (purchased 2 houses, refinanced once, hopefully soon to be twice), I have yet to be asked for my resume, any references from current or former employers, nor has a lender ever asked for my current budget. Lenders do check your credit history, but that only gives a view into the borrower's credit, and not a view of their overall financial state. It would also seem useful for a lender to have a Balance sheet (list of assets, liabilities), and they do ask about assets, but not a complete picture of financial state.  Lenders do ask that you have 2 years of employment in the same field (which is very little considering the long tail of the loan, 30 years in many cases).

- Would a Lender want an Income Statement? (essentially a budget, showing income versus expenses - would they discard the information, use it to support the loan documentation, or mine it for problems?)
- Would a Lender want a Balance Sheet?
- Would a Lender want a resume? (especially if you have a long employment history in a high-demand field)?

Answer (score 1):

I have never had a lender ask my budget, only my income, savings, credit rating and value of the collateral. That's considered adequate info to estimate risk for most ordinary loans.

Yes, they may want the income proven by evidence from your employer or via a copy of your tax returns.

They don't care what you buy as long as there's evidence you'll make loan payments on time for the life of the loan.

Comment: Budget? How easy it would be to produce a beautiful work of fiction, no eating out, no vacations, etc. My own refi experience is similar to yours.